# Click on view during animation doesn't react

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, android-view, objectanimator

I have a simple animation:

```
<rotate android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="180"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="4"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" />

<translate
    android:duration="2000"
    android:fromXDelta="10%p"
    android:toXDelta="90%p"
    android:repeatCount="1"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:fillAfter="true"/>
```

and I run it on an `ImageView`.  I have an onclick event setup on the `ImageView`:

```
    imgCorrect1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d(TAG, "explode ");
        }
    });
```

Here is how I start the animation:

```
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rottrans);
imgCorrect1.startAnimation(Anim1);
```

The problem is that while the animation is going, the onclick doesn't get called while the animation is running if I tap on the image while it's animating.

I have tried to search on this issue, but the posts are all to animate an `ImageView` -when- the onclick is called, not the opposite.

I hope I have been clear here in the description.  I have tried to provide all of the relevant code to explain the issue.

Comment: try setting onTouchListener with MotionEvent. ACTION_DOWN

Comment: I will look into that.  Haven't messed with that.  going to have to do some research.  thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [`Animation`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html) API, which animates the matrix of the view. Thus you see a *ghost* of the original view being animated, whereas the view still is positioned in the original place.

Instead, use [Animator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.html) API. Here's how it may look like:

```
        ImageView imageView = ...;

        ObjectAnimator rotate = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, View.ROTATION, 0, 180);
        rotate.setRepeatCount(4);
        rotate.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
        rotate.setDuration(1000);
        rotate.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());

        ObjectAnimator translate = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, View.TRANSLATION_X, 0, 100);
        translate.setRepeatCount(1);
        translate.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
        translate.setDuration(2000);

        AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();

        // Play either sequentially or together
        set.playSequentially(rotate, translate);
        // set.playTogether(rotate, translate);

        set.start();
```

Comment: Just to give an update, this solution works the way I wanted.  Thanks!  I have upvoted.